# python "or" when one of the vars might not exist?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

Assume something like this:

```
if mylist[0] == 1 or mylist[12] == 2:
   # do something
```

But I'm not sure if `mylist[12]` will always not be out of range. What do to keep things simple and still check if index exists? Wouldn't want to do

```
if mylist[0] == 1:
    # do something
elif mylist[12] == 2:
    # do the EXACT same thing
```

As you get too much identical lines of code.

Comment: What's so special about the number `12` that you want to check this specific index by number, but not special enough to make sure the list is long enough ahead of time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could check the length of the list:

```
if mylist[0] == 1 or (len(mylist) > 12 and mylist[12] == 2):
```

This uses the [short-circuting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) behaviour of `and` to ensure that `mylist[12]` won't be evaluated if the list has 12 items or fewer.

Answer (score 4):

Slicing always returns a value (even if it's an empty list). You could do:

```
if myList[0] == 1 or myList[12:13] == [2]:
```

Comment: It should work, but is less clear than Mark's answer. Although because it works, I am upvoting it.

Comment: @Tadeck: Yeah, I think Mark's answer is better as well. Just thought I'd throw my 2 cents in though.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you think it's more readable, like so:

```
if mylist[0] == 1:
    # do something
elif len(mylist) > 12 and mylist[12] == 2:
    # do same thing
```

Comment: ...but i prefer @Mark's answer because you aren't writing the same code twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get(arr, ind, default=None):
    try:
        return arr[ind]
    except IndexError:
        return default

if get(myList, 0)==1 or get(myList, 12)==2:
    # do something
```